# Getting NaN as a result for my JS function. Could anyone explain why?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I'm new to Javascript, so please bear with me. I wrote a function that returns the difference between the highest and lowest number in an array:

```js
// FUNCTION 1
function range (arr) {
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var max_diff = max - min;
  return max_diff;
}
console.log(range([6,2,3,4,9,6,1,0,5])); // 9
```

However, before I came up with this solution, I tried another approach:

```js
// FUNCTION 2
function range (arr) {
  var max = function (arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  }
  var min = function (arr) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  }
  var max_diff = max - min;
  return max_diff;
}
console.log(range([6,2,3,4,9,6,1,0,5])); // NaN
```

This function returns "NaN". I read up on NaN, but it's still not clear to me why I get "NaN" as a result.

The other strange thing is: if I put FUNCTION 2 before FUNCTION 1, the second function actually returns the correct result (9).

Whaaaat?

Comment: Ehm, you're subtracting two functions from one another. Not the results of the functions. A function in Javascript is an object, but it is not a number.

Comment: max and minimum is function so you should use  max() - min();

Comment: In a simplified example, `42` and `function() { return 42; }` are two very different values. You can read a tutorial about functions here: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting two functions, `max` and `min`. So the functions are first coerced to primitive values, then coerced to numbers, and then subtracted.

When coerced to primitives, functions return an implementation-dependent string representation of their code. Most probably this is not coercible to a number, so you get `NaN`, i.e., not-a-number. Subtracting `NaN`s produces `NaN`.

Maybe you wanted to run IIFEs (immediately-invoked function expressions) instead:

```js
// FUNCTION 2
function range (arr) {
  var max = function () {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  }(); // <-- max is the value returned by calling the function
  var min = function () {
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  }(); // <-- min is the value returned by calling the function
  var max_diff = max - min;
  return max_diff;
}
console.log(range([6,2,3,4,9,6,1,0,5])); // 9
```

Comment: Ah, get it. I guess in my mind I wasn't operating with two functions, but the value returned by the two functions min and max.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you never invoke the function, and because of that your max and min variables are functions instead of numbers.

You can use an IIFE (invoke the function after declaring it)

```js
// FUNCTION 2
function range (arr) {
  var max = (function (arr) { return Math.max.apply(null, arr); }(arr));
  var min = (function (arr) { return Math.min.apply(null, arr); }(arr));
  var max_diff = max - min;
  return max_diff;
}
console.log(range([6,2,3,4,9,6,1,0,5])); // NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You recieved NaN since you subtracted two methods:

```
isNaN(function(){} - function(){}) === true; // true
```

You need to invoke the methods and subtract their results:

```js
function range (arr) {
  // method
  var max = function (arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  }
  
  // method
  var min = function (arr) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  }
  
  // invoke the methods
  var max_diff = max(arr) - min(arr);

  return max_diff;
}

document.write(range([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]));
```

BTW, since you are using a function, you don't need to pass an array on each call:

```
function range (arr) {
  // no need to pass arr
  var max = function () {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  }

  // no need to pass arr
  var min = function () {
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  }

  // invoke the methods without passing arr
  var max_diff = max() - min();

  return max_diff;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So helpful. That was exactly my problem (thinking that I'm subtracting the function results, but indeed just trying to subtract the functions). Thanks.